# I like the HTC interface additions to Android, but I have a non-HTC phone. Is there a way I can get them anyway?

Tags: htc-sense, user-interface

From the [list of on-topic questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238?tab=ontopic&phase=definition#tab-top) in this SE's definition phase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this, you would need a rooted phone, and flash a custom ROM with the HTC interface (called Sense) built in. Depending on your phone, it may or may not be there (more likely not).